# ADMIN FIREBASE AUTH - NODE JS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have a problem [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kPXQ.png), and the code [code in node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6SV.png) that is in nodejs, I use firebase admin and it turns out that it doesn't let me create users now I get this error, and a few days ago it worked normally, and I have no idea why what reason started to have problems now

I tried to update the node, the sdk of firebase admin and change, but in itself it is the Auth function of firebase Admin

**CODIGO**

```
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Configura la aplicación de Firebase Admin con las credenciales de tu proyecto
const serviceAccount = require("./.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const db = admin.firestore();


app.post("/newVig", (req, res) => {
  const { mapa, documentoId } = req.body;
  const nuevosDatos = JSON.parse(mapa);
  // Crear el usuario en Firebase Authentication
  admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: nuevosDatos.email,
      password: nuevosDatos.pass,
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      // Obtener el ID del usuario recién creado
      const userId = userRecord.uid;

      // Almacenar el ID del usuario en Firestore
      const db = admin.firestore();
      const userDocRef = db.collection("users").doc(userId);
      nuevosDatos.uid = userId;
      userDocRef.set(nuevosDatos).then((userRecord) => {
        // Obtener el ID del usuario recién creado

        // Almacenar el ID del usuario en Firestore
        const db = admin.firestore();

        const conjuntoDocRef = db.collection("conjuntos").doc(documentoId);

        // Agregar el ID del usuario al campo "celadoresids" del documento en la colección "conjuntos"
        return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
          return transaction.get(conjuntoDocRef).then((conjuntoDoc) => {
            if (!conjuntoDoc.exists) {
              throw new Error("El documento del conjunto no existe.");
            }

            // Obtener el array actual de celadoresids (puede ser un array vacío si no hay celadores aún)
            const celadoresIdsArray = conjuntoDoc.data().porteriaids || [];
            console.log(celadoresIdsArray);
            // Agregar el nuevo ID del usuario al array de celadoresids
            celadoresIdsArray.push(userId);

            // Actualizar el campo "celadoresids" en el documento del conjunto
            transaction.update(conjuntoDocRef, {
              porteriaids: celadoresIdsArray,
            });
          });
        });
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Usuario creado exitosamente.");
      res.sendStatus(200); // Enviar una respuesta exitosa al cliente
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error al crear el usuario:", error);

      res.sendStatus(500); // Enviar una respuesta de error al cliente
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.